# Bound of logarithmic integral function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Does [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) bound from above the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)? In other words, does it hold that $\pi(x) \le li(x)$ or even $\pi(x)\le Li(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Which is larger changes infinitely many times. This is what [Skewes' number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number) is about.